# Am i doing something wrong with LinkExtractor attributes (restrict_xpath)? not doing callback

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm testing rules to set up a spider on a website in order to enter to the url of each item, get information from each and then follow the pagination, in this case is infinite scrolling.
But first I wanted to create a rule for Callback to get called  every time it finds an item, but the problem is, that it's not going for callback.

I've tried allow() with a bare minimum expression also and still don't  get nothing. The only time I'm getting anything is if I leave allow() and restric_xpaths() both empty.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor 
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class Bahiaprop1Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bahiaprop1'
    allowed_domains = ['www.bahiablancapropiedades.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.bahiablancapropiedades.com/buscar#/terrenos/venta/bahia- 
blanca/todos-los-barrios/rango-min=50.000,rango-max=350.000']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths = ('//div[@class="row"]')),
                        callback = 'parse_item', follow = True),
)


def parse_item(self, response):
    print ('lol')
```

I expect "lol" to be printed.

Comment: It seems that the data gets loaded with something like Javascript. That means you may need some tools like selenium or whatsoever to be able to retrieve the data after it has been loaded (mock a real user). You can also look in the developer tools and see if any API call or request is made. In the 1 minute I was looking in the developer tools with your page open, I saw a POST-request was made to https://www.bahiablancapropiedades.com/buscar/resultados/0 for example, which seems to return HTML that is being displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that the selector you're using (`//div[@class="row"]`) only matches `div`'s with a single class `row`. 
Using XPath expressions, to match elements *containing* a class is a bit tricky:

```xml
//div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' row ')]
```

or you could use css selectors instead:

```py
Rule(
    LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css = 'div.row'),
    callback = 'parse_item', 
)
```

*EDIT:*

Some links:

- [Parsel (the library Scrapy uses for parsing)](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)
- [A XPath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Would you tell me where can i learn more about selectors?